# Path.join cross platform in Nodejs for require

Tags: node.js, path, cross-platform, filepath

I remember long time ago in Node js, it was needed to use path.join in order to load local modules cross-platform. I simply want to know still do we need such strategy or it is not needed anymore for Node 12+?

Thanks

E.g.

```
const i= require(path.join(__dirname,'config','myModule'))
```

instead of writing

```
const i=require('./config/module')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will work just fine and have been just fine in node.js for as long as I can remember.  The module loading rules for `require()` are fully documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).  Your specific case should be covered by the very first section and step 3a which is this:

```
require(X) from module at path Y
1. If X is a core module,
   a. return the core module
   b. STOP
2. If X begins with '/'
   a. set Y to be the filesystem root
3. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
   a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
```

The times when you may need to use `path.join()` are when you may be constructing a path that you will send to some external module that requires OS-specific path separators or when you just want `path.join()` to handle making sure there is one and only one path separator between pieces you are joining (like when you don't know if individual pieces already have leading or trailing slashes).

`require()` itself will work fine with `/` as a path separator on any supported platform so `require('./config/module')` will be fine on Windows even though the OS path separator is `\`.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on the following parts? 
`when you may be constructing a path that you will send to some external module that requires OS-specific path separators`. 

And also this one:
`or when you just want path.join() to handle making sure there is one and only one path separator between pieces you are joining`

if you can show some examples that help picture those cases, it would be nice